# solace creates multi connection with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, solace

i try to use solace with spring boot.

here is a demo application and the log its create:
https://github.com/GreenRover/solace_spring_multiconnection/blob/master/problem.log

I wonder about this error (INFO) message
c.s.jcsmp.impl.SessionModeSupport   ....  - Error Response (400) - Already Exists

Is it normal to get this message or goes something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message indicates that a queue fails to be created because a queue with the same name already exists.

This is expected since your sample code tries to create a queue with the same name more than once. It is ok to ignore this message.

However, if you want to avoid the message, the application has to make sure that only one queue is created with the name.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. But it's hard to interpret from this error. I suspected a duplicated username / duplicated connection.